# The integral of an irrational function

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials

I wish someone could help me derive this expression. ($K$ is a constant coefficient. $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial function of degree n.)
$$
\int\frac{P_n(x)\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}} \equiv P_{n-1}(x)  \cdot\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} + K\cdot\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}, (a\neq0) 
$$
After finding the derivatives of both sides it is easy to find the coefficients of the polynomial $P_{n-1}(x)$. Then we are left with this simple integral:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$$

Comment: What is your question, do you want to evaluate the integral at the bottom?

Comment: No, I want a proof this formula is legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider$$\int\frac{P(x)}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}\,dx = Q(x)  \,\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} + K\,\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$$ Differentating both side and simplifying; it gives
$$2P(x)=(2a x+b)\, Q(x)+2( a x^2+ b x+c+K)\, Q'(x)$$ If $a\neq 0$, the lhs is of degree $n$ and the rhs of degree $p+1$ is $p$ is the degree of $Q(x)$.

So, $p=n-1$.